# ORDER BY FIELD() not in

Tags: sql

I have a set of records which I need to sort in particular order. Basically I need to sort like:

```
select * from Table 
ORDER BY FIELD(code, 'int', (<> 'int' and <> 'nat'), 'nat')
```

Or

```
select * from Table 
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 5, >= 10, 7)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this conditional sorting meets your requirement:

```
select * from Table
order by case
  when id = 5 then 1
  when id >= 10 then 2
  when id = 7 then 3
  else 4
end
```

or for the 1st case:

```
select * from Table
order by case
  when code = 'int' then 1
  when code <> 'nat' then 2
  else 3
end
```

Comment: what is 1, 2 3 here in the Then part?

Comment: They define the order. So the id = 5 will be 1st, the ids >=10 will be sorted after id = 5, then id = 7 and last all the rest.

Comment: You may also need additional sorting after `end` like `...end, id` so that ids like `15` and `12` will be sorted: `12, 15` and not `15, 12`since they have the same order priority.

Answer (score 0):

From your second select statement, You can try -

```
select * from Table 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 5 THEN 1
              WHEN id BETWEEN 6 AND 10 AND id NOT <> 7 THEN 2
              WHEN id = 7 THEN 3 END)
```

Comment: You could simply define conditions for 1 and 3, and everything `ELSE` becomes 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use multiple keys in `order by`:

```
order by (id = 5) desc,   -- "5" first
         (id = 7) asc     -- "7" last
```

I am using MySQL syntax because `FIELD()` is a MySQL function.